# JQuery CSS Opacity Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I've had a look everywhere, and can't seem to find an answer that works for me. I'm setting the opacity of the long panoramic style images using JQuery's CSS method on this page: http://www.prideoftameside.co.uk/default-redesign.htm.

In Chrome, all is well, it works nicely and animates between the divs. In IE however it doesn't set the opacity. I've tried setting the zoom on those elements, and the parents, but it's not working at all. Does anyone know of any fix that might work?

The bit of code to concentrate on (that isn't working) is:

```
$('.introimg:not(:eq(0))').css({ 'opacity' : '0' });
$('.introimg:eq(0)').css({ 'opacity' : '1' });
```

Thanks,

James

Comment: I'd imagine it's the transition code in the css that's the problem.  Post that, or look into the jQuery `animate()` function instead.

Comment: IE 6/7/8 doesn't support the opacity css that you're trying to use there I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi, actually as Jasper mentions below this should be cross browser compatible thanks to JQuery, so that's not the issue. If I set it to the header image, it works on IE, so I'm really puzzled as to why it won't work on those images. Also, just for the record I'm testing in IE 9, which should still support opacity.

I don't think it's the transition code either, as it works on Chrome and Firefox. I've added animate() to the images, and still no luck.

Comment: I still don't know what the issue is, but I have found some kind of solution. Instead of applying the opacity to the introimg div, I've applied it to the children, and that for some strange reason has worked in all browsers. The working version is at: http://www.prideoftameside.co.uk/default-redesign2.htm, and I'm using fadeTo() now (it still didn't solve the original problem, and seems to be using the same ideas as I did with opacity). If anyone can solve this please let me know, as it will make my code a lot better. I've left the old non-working (in IE) page in the original question link.

Answer (score 0):

For IE < 9 you can't use the "opacity" property.
I'm not sure if it's your issue, but try this:

Instead of opacity, use

```
filter : alpha(opacity=100);
```

With jQuery:

```
$('.item').css({ 'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=100);' });
```

Comment: jQuery does this browser compatibility for you.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it's one of the many fixes I've tried that hasn't worked. I've added it to prove it, and still no luck in IE. I've also added some garbled code that's apparently meant to work in IE8, but doesn't.